# Uninstall npm without using npm - is it possible?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, npm

I was manually updating node and npm. I am using them from Visual Studio only. Typing *any* npm command e.g.

```
npm --version
```

causes the process to hang and CPU consumption goes max. So I cannot uninstall or reinstall npm with npm commands. Node seems to work fine. I am using Node version 6.3.1 and it responds normally to

```
node --version
```

Calling

```
where node
```

gives only one result.

What I have done so far:

1. Upgraded Node.js outside VS2015 using command prompt.
2. Uninstalled Node together with npm from command prompt.
3. Deleted Node program folder and all subfolders
4. Uninstalled Visual Studio 2015
5. Installed VS 2017 RC.

Even after this last step, the behavior of npm is the same - it hangs. Visual Studio refuses to build at all.

I hope my problems will be solved when npm starts to work again. So I figure next to try is to uninstall npm alone followed by a reinstall. How can I do that without using npm?

Comment: If I run the command: "node npm-cli.js --version" from the npm folder it returns "3.10.3". So I guess the problem is in the npm.cmd file. But I didn't change that file...

Comment: It seems that it is this loop that doesn't end in my installation...
 "FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('CALL "%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" prefix -g') DO (
  SET "NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS=%%F\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
)"

Answer (score 1):

Use the following process:

- Delete `%appdata%\npm` and `%appdata%\npm-cache`.
- Edit your PATH and remove everything that references npm (to do so, hit "Start" and search for `env`).
- Reinstall Node, then install [this tool](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade) - and only use [this tool](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade) to upgrade npm, do not attempt to run `npm install npm`.

**References**

- [Microsoft NodeJS Guidelines](https://github.com/microsoft/nodejs-guidelines)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am unable to verify it at this point, as I was forced to do a reinstall of my system to overcome the issue. If someone else experience the same issue, please add a comment if this answer solves the issue.